# Google speech to text not working for small audio

Tags: python, google-api, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I wanted it to recognise a speaker speaking a letter(.28 secs worth of audio) but it gives unknown value error

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r=sr.Recognizer()

l1=sr.AudioFile("clips/a.wav")
l2=sr.AudioFile("clips/B.wav")
with l1 as source:
   a1=r.record(source,offset=.28,duration=.28)
with l2 as source:
   a2=r.record(source) 

 print(r.recognize_google(a1))
```

*speech_recognition.UnknownValueError*

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Comment: added the code.

Comment: Thank you. What error message do you receive exactly? Please copy paste into the question.

Comment: @timotree added the error

Comment: I am no expert, but if your file (`clips/a.wav`) is .28 seconds long, starting at `offset=.28` would mean starting at the end of the recording. Does removing the `offset=.28` part solve the problem?

Comment: @timotree here the duration means that it will take .28 sec of audio after .28 sec, i.e.taking the audio from .28-.56 sec